# How to select values of one table based on values of another table in SQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 5 tables:

```
user ( user id, user name, etc.. )
role ( role_id, role_name )
user_role ( user_id, roles_id )
form ( form_id, form_name, etc.. )
form_access ( form_id, role_id )
```

- `user` contains all registered user data.
- `role` contains all different types of roles.
- `user_role` contains which user has which role (all assigned roles are stored)
- `form` contains all form data.
- `form_access` contains data like which user role has which form access(one form can be assigned to many user roles).

I wanted to write a SQL query in PHP to retrieve form name based on the user logged in and his role, e.g. if Admin logs in he should get all forms, if HR logs in he should get forms related to HR only.

I tried this query:

```
$query = "SELECT ur.role_id, f.form_name, f.form_desc 
          FROM user_role ur, froms f
          WHERE users.id = '".$user."',
                users.status ='A',
                forms.form_id = form_access.form_id,
                from_access.role_id = user_role.role_id,
                user_role.role_id = '".$user."'";`
```

Some one help me out with the correct query?

Comment: 1. So what is wrong? 2. You've misspelled a table name "froms". 3. You're given the tables aliases but not used them, 4.The only 2 tables in the FROM clause are user_role and forms(/froms) but you're then using form_access (+ from_access) and users in your WHERE clause.

Comment: This is edited one @OGHaza yet its not working                             `$qury = "SELECT ur.role_id, f.form_name, f.form_desc 
         FROM user_role ur, 
              froms f,
              users u,
              form_access fa
         WHERE users.id = '".$user."',
               u.status ='A',
               f.form_id = fa.form_id,
               fa.role_id = ur.role_id,
               ur.role_id = '".$user."'";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AND .

BUT this should be better with joins.

```
$query = "SELECT ur.role_id, f.form_name, f.form_desc 
          FROM from_access  
          INNER JOIN  froms f  ON forms.form_id = form_access.form_id  
          INNER JOIN user_role ur ON from_access.role_id = user_role.role_id 
          INNER JOIN users ON users.id = user_role.role_id
          WHERE users.id = '".$user."' 
            AND users.status ='A'  ";
```

Comment: I think the condition "user_role.role_id ='".$user."'" should be "user_role.user_id = '".$user."'"

Comment: yeah i am trying the edited answer but i am unable to retrieve data

Comment: i just wanted to get form_name from forms based on assigned role to logged in user i have user id...

Answer (score 0):

Since you start from the user_id you'll want to select from `user_role` and JOIN `form_access` and `form`.

```
SELECT `form`.`form_name` AS `form_name` 
FROM `user_role` AS `ur` 
INNER JOIN `form_access` AS `fa` ON `fa`.`role_id` = `ur`.`role_id`
INNER JOIN `form` AS `f` ON `f`.`form_id` = `fa`.`form_id`
WHERE `ur`.`user_id` = '".$user."'
```

PS: Check the table and column names.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is entirely broken, the others may have provided you with solutions but I'm going to give you some advice.

You've written an entire query, tried it, and it failed. I write queries all day long but if I write a whole query in Notepad then execute it it's probably going to have some minor error in it somewhere too.

Start from the ground up. You're trying to get a list of forms the user has access to, so lets start with the `forms_access` table. So what's the most basic starting point? How about:

```
SELECT fa.role_id, fa.form_id
FROM forms_access fa
```

Ok, thats overly simplified but if that ran at least we know we're connected to the database.

So we can easily tell which `form_id`s each role has access to. Now we know our linking table to `users` is `user_roles`, so let's add that in:

```
SELECT ur.user_id, fa.form_id, fa.role_id 
FROM forms_access fa
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON fa.role_id = ur.role_id
```

So we've joined `forms_access` to `user_roles` on the foreign key `role_id`. Now we can see for every `user_id`, which `role_id` they have and which `form_id`s they can access.

So we're pretty much there, we just need the information from the `forms` table, so lets JOIN to that too:

```
SELECT ur.user_id, f.form_name, f.form_desc, fa.form_id, fa.role_id 
FROM forms_access fa
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id = fa.role_id
INNER JOIN forms f ON f.form_id = ur.form_id
```

Great! Now we have a list of each `form_name/form_desc` that each `user_id` can access.

Try the above step by step, if you skip to the end there could well be an error since I have not tested the code, and I don't know for sure that your table definitions match the question. If you do it step by step you only need to check the most recently added line to find the error.

I have just noticed in the question that you also need `users.status = 'A'`, so in the same way as above you'll need to join to the users table on an appropriate foreign key, give it a go.

Now, once you've done all that you need to filter the results to a specific user_id - notice up till this point we haven't bothered with the WHERE clause.

Now don't go adding some variant of `WHERE user_id = '$user'` right away because then you've introduced 2 potential errors. Instead try adding `WHERE user_id = 0` (or some known user_id). Does the query run and the results look correct? Great, now finally try adding in your php variable.